# Example of open source projects using scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

Can anybody point me to any open source project that make use of [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)?

I'm even interested in those that may use scalaz in some small ways (mixed with other programming style or just pulling a few things from scalaz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one example that is current though in its early stage:

https://github.com/krasserm/scalaz-camel

> This project provides a domain-specific language (DSL) for Apache Camel that is based on the Scala programming language and the Scalaz library.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'm looking for. It uses `Promise`, `Strategy` and some *kleisli* stuff and will help me understand more of scalaz.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look on GitHub?

https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=scalaz&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't looked at github search. Aside from scalaz itself, scalaz-camel that dpp mentioned and the scalaz-depend skeleton, it mostly seems to be personal projects and code demos.